# Draw polygon along line feature

Tags: features, drawing

I have some line features from a nautical chart representing dikes I'm trying to bring into another program that wants polygons.  I was wondering if there were a tool in QGIS or ArcMAP that would let me maybe take a line, have an attribute for a width and draw a polygon that wide along the vertices of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see the [buffer tool in QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html) or the [buffer tool in ArcGIS](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm).